# Idiomatic expression about concern or worries with "stomach"

Tags: idioms

Is there an idiom with "stomach" that expresses **one's concern/worries** about something, something like "I got so worried that my stomach hurts" & stuff?

Comment: *Get butterflies in one's stomach*?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that & it means to get nervous, not worried.

Comment: Must the idiom contain only the word *stomach*? Worry-related idioms often involve the gut or viscera, or cause nausea.

Comment: More-or-less the opposite: [have a strong stomach](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-strong-stomach).

Comment: @rajah9 - in British usage (I don't know about elsewhere) it is common to use 'stomach' to mean the whole digestive tract, and to use that word to talk about symptoms that really occur further along the tract, e.g. "I had a stomach upset" when a pedantic anatomist might want to say "bowel upset". This is politeness; we do not want the listener to be forced to imagine faeces, diarrhoea, toilets, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the expression:

***[pit of one's stomach](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pit+of+stomach)***:

> Fig. the middle of one's stomach; the location of a "visceral response." “*I got a strange feeling in the pit of my stomach when they told me the bad news.”*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

Answer (score 16):

The adverse stimulus can be described **as stomach-churning**:

> ADJECTIVE If you describe something as *stomach-churning*, you mean
>   that it is so unpleasant that it makes you feel physically sick.
>
> - *The stench from rotting food is stomach-churning.*
> - .*..that rush of stomach-churning fear at the sound of a mortar exploding nearby.*
>
> [Collins COBUILD Advanced English
>   Dictionary.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stomach-churning)

As with Cobuild's second example above, example sentences from [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stomach-churning) show the at least partially metaphorical broadening, certainly involving dread:

> •  *For much of the past week I have had this dreadful, stomach-churning*
>   *feeling of imminent disaster.*
>
> •  *At the end of every set of three*
>   *levels a stomach-churning guardian awaits.*

while [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stomach-churning) highlights the dread-inspiring nature:

> - *stomach-churning*: making you feel very frightened, nervous, or ill

Answer (score 7):

*“To worry oneself sick [about or over something]”* is one – the word “sick” implies a state of nausea or illness.

*“I worried myself sick about the exam results.”*

*“To be sick to the stomach of/with something”* = to be irritated and annoyed by something but this is old-fashioned and is now reduced to “to be sick of/with [a repeated action]”

*“I am sick to the stomach of your constantly complaining about everything I do!”* (old-fashioned)

*“I am sick to the stomach with your constant complaints about everything I do!”* (old-fashioned)

*“I am sick of your constantly complaining about everything I do!”* (Current)

*“I am sick of your constant complaints about everything I do!”* (Current)

Comment: I've just realised that the usual expression is "I'm sick to **my** stomach of ..." etc. Add a reference (eg CED, M-W) listing 'sick to one's / my stomach' and I'll restore my upvote.

Answer (score 5):

**Have one's stomach (tied) in knots**

used to say that a person has an unpleasant and tight feeling in the stomach, usually from nervousness

> Her stomach was (tied) in knots as she awaited the start of competition.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-knots)

Answer (score 4):

**Have butterflies (in your stomach):** to feel very nervous, usually about something you are going to do.

**Example:** I had terrible butterflies before I gave that talk in Venice. ([Cambridge English dictionary)](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/have-butterflies-in-your-stomach)

Comment: Yeah, I checked that & it means to get nervous, not worried.

Answer (score 2):

Another expression I don´t see mentioned is "turns my stomach" - e.g. "Seeing something like that really turns my stomach".  The general meaning is that it induces nausea, stomach agitation, or makes one want to vomit due to being distasteful or disgusting.

Variants are "makes my stomach turn", "turns one's stomach", etc.  Reference: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-sb-s-stomach

Answer (score 1):

Another common idiom would be

> [This bad thing] made me sick to my stomach

[This Reddit uses it](https://www.reddit.com/r/FemaleDatingStrategy/comments/eukvus/finally_watched_bombshell_and_it_made_me_sick_to/)

> Finally watched "Bombshell" and it made me sick to my stomach.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use a random Reddit post as a source for a phrase and/or its use.  Surely there's a dictionary that defines or explains the phrase which would be a better source?  For example https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sick-to-your-stomach

Answer (score 1):

'Cannot stomach x,' is often used to represent x being too hard to handle (usually for a person).

For example, 'Johnny was never a good soldier because he couldn't stomach killing.'

Source: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cannot+stomach

Comment: Good, but could you [edit] your answer to give a referenced definition of the phrase?

Comment: While *ambient* is a reasonable suggestion, this answer was "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Would you be able to flesh it out to give it the dignity it deserves - and head off getting deleted?